# Winhttp.h error during compile process: 'WinHttpOpen' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gcc, g++

I try figure out, why gcc/g++ compiler throw error likie this:

```
.\http.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\http.cpp:14:5: error: 'WinHttpOpen' was not declared in this scope
     WinHttpOpen(  L"A WinHTTP Example Program/1.0", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
```

Below i put my code. It is pretty weird, because i wrote that code according to in MSDN Documentation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib");

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    bool bResults = false;
    // HINTERNET hSession = NULL;
    // HINTERNET hConnect = NULL;
    // HINTERNET hRequest = NULL;

    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    WinHttpOpen(  L"A WinHTTP Example Program/1.0", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    // Specify an HTTP server.
    // if (hSession)
    //     hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, L"www.wp.pl",
    //                                INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);

    // // Create an HTTP Request handle.
    // if (hConnect)
    //     hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", 
    //                                    L"/writetst.txt", 
    //                                    NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
    //                                    WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 
    //                                    0);

    // Send a Request.
    // if (hRequest) 
    //     bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest, 
    //                                    WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
    //                                    0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 
    //                                    0, 0);

    // Place additional code here.


    // Report errors.
    // if (!bResults)
    //     printf("Error %d has occurred.\n",GetLastError());

    // // Close open handles.
    // if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    // if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    // if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    return 0;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion?I commented out part of code, but it really doesn't matter, error is always the same.

---

edit:

Operation system: Windows 10 x64,

IDE: Visual Studio Code,

Compiler: gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

I followed for suggestion @Han and i have code like below:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>


int main(void){

    HINTERNET hSession = NULL; // here is problem
    HINTERNET hConnect = NULL; // here is problem
    HINTERNET hRequest = NULL; // here is problem
    bool bResults = false;


    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    WinHttpOpen(  L"A WinHTTP Example Program/1.0", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: if i delete HINSTANCE variables, compiler will work correctly, but if i add those variables, compiler will throw an exception like below:

```
PS > g++.exe .\http.cpp -o http.exe -lwinhttp
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:32:9: error: 'LPVOID' does not name a type; did you mean 'VOID'?
 typedef LPVOID HINTERNET;
         ^~~~~~
         VOID
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:33:9: error: 'HINTERNET' does not name a type; did you mean 'INTERNETAPI'?
 typedef HINTERNET *LPHINTERNET;
         ^~~~~~~~~
         INTERNETAPI
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:38:9: error: 'WORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
 typedef WORD INTERNET_PORT;
         ^~~~
         HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:39:9: error: 'INTERNET_PORT' does not name a type; did you mean 'INTERNETAPI_'?
 typedef INTERNET_PORT *LPINTERNET_PORT;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
         INTERNETAPI_
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:465:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD   dwStructSize;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:466:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR  lpszScheme;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:467:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD   dwSchemeLength;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:469:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR  lpszHostName;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:470:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD   dwHostNameLength;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:471:5: error: 'INTERNET_PORT' does not name a type; did you mean 'INTERNETAPI_'?
     INTERNET_PORT nPort;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
     INTERNETAPI_
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:472:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR  lpszUserName;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:473:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD   dwUserNameLength;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:474:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR  lpszPassword;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:475:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD   dwPasswordLength;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:476:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR  lpszUrlPath;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:477:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD   dwUrlPathLength;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:478:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR  lpszExtraInfo;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:479:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD   dwExtraInfoLength;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:486:5: error: 'DWORD_PTR' does not name a type
     DWORD_PTR dwResult;
     ^~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:487:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD dwError;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:492:5: error: 'FILETIME' does not name a type; did you mean 'ETIME'?
     FILETIME ftExpiry;
     ^~~~~~~~
     ETIME
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:493:5: error: 'FILETIME' does not name a type; did you mean 'ETIME'?
     FILETIME ftStart;
     ^~~~~~~~
     ETIME
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:494:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR lpszSubjectInfo;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:495:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR lpszIssuerInfo;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:496:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR lpszProtocolName;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:497:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR lpszSignatureAlgName;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:498:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR lpszEncryptionAlgName;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:499:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD dwKeySize;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:504:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD dwAccessType;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:505:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR lpszProxy;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:506:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR lpszProxyBypass;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:513:5: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
     WINBOOL   fAutoDetect;
     ^~~~~~~
     V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:514:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR lpszAutoConfigUrl;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:515:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR lpszProxy;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:516:5: error: 'LPWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPWSTR lpszProxyBypass;
     ^~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:519:15: error: typedef 'VOID' is initialized (use decltype instead)
 typedef VOID (CALLBACK *WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK)(HINTERNET,DWORD_PTR,DWORD,LPVOID,DWORD);
               ^~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:519:15: error: 'CALLBACK' was not declared in this scope
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:519:15: note: the macro 'CALLBACK' had not yet been defined
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:8,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:69,
                 from .\http.cpp:3:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/minwindef.h:90: note: it was later defined here
 #define CALLBACK __stdcall

In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:519:25: error: 'WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK' was not declared in this scope
 typedef VOID (CALLBACK *WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK)(HINTERNET,DWORD_PTR,DWORD,LPVOID,DWORD);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:519:25: note: suggested alternative: 'WINHTTP_OPTION_CALLBACK'
 typedef VOID (CALLBACK *WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK)(HINTERNET,DWORD_PTR,DWORD,LPVOID,DWORD);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         WINHTTP_OPTION_CALLBACK
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:531:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD dwFlags;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:532:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD dwAutoDetectFlags;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:533:5: error: 'LPCWSTR' does not name a type; did you mean 'LPTR'?
     LPCWSTR lpszAutoConfigUrl;
     ^~~~~~~
     LPTR
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:534:5: error: 'LPVOID' does not name a type; did you mean 'VOID'?
     LPVOID lpvReserved;
     ^~~~~~
     VOID
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:535:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD dwReserved;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:536:5: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
     WINBOOL fAutoLogonIfChallenged;
     ^~~~~~~
     V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:541:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD dwMajorVersion;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:542:5: error: 'DWORD' does not name a type; did you mean 'HIWORD'?
     DWORD dwMinorVersion;
     ^~~~~
     HIWORD
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:558:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(HINTERNET,LPCWSTR,DWORD,DWORD);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:559:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl(DWORD,LPWSTR*);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:560:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpCheckPlatform(void);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:561:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpCloseHandle(HINTERNET);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:562:1: error: 'HINTERNET' does not name a type; did you mean 'INTERNETAPI'?
 HINTERNET   WINAPI WinHttpConnect(HINTERNET,LPCWSTR,INTERNET_PORT,DWORD);
 ^~~~~~~~~
 INTERNETAPI
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:563:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpCrackUrl(LPCWSTR,DWORD,DWORD,LPURL_COMPONENTS);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:564:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpCreateUrl(LPURL_COMPONENTS,DWORD,LPWSTR,LPDWORD);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:565:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration(WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO*);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:566:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG*);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:567:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(HINTERNET,LPCWSTR,WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_OPTIONS*,WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO*);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:568:1: error: 'HINTERNET' does not name a type; did you mean 'INTERNETAPI'?
 HINTERNET   WINAPI WinHttpOpen(LPCWSTR,DWORD,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,DWORD);
 ^~~~~~~~~
 INTERNETAPI
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:569:1: error: 'HINTERNET' does not name a type; did you mean 'INTERNETAPI'?
 HINTERNET   WINAPI WinHttpOpenRequest(HINTERNET,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR*,DWORD);
 ^~~~~~~~~
 INTERNETAPI
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:570:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpQueryAuthParams(HINTERNET,DWORD,LPVOID*);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:571:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpQueryAuthSchemes(HINTERNET,LPDWORD,LPDWORD,LPDWORD);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:572:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(HINTERNET,LPDWORD);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:573:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpQueryHeaders(HINTERNET,DWORD,LPCWSTR,LPVOID,LPDWORD,LPDWORD);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:574:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpQueryOption(HINTERNET,DWORD,LPVOID,LPDWORD);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:575:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpReadData(HINTERNET,LPVOID,DWORD,LPDWORD);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:576:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpReceiveResponse(HINTERNET,LPVOID);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:577:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpSendRequest(HINTERNET,LPCWSTR,DWORD,LPVOID,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD_PTR);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:578:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpSetDefaultProxyConfiguration(WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO*);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:579:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpSetCredentials(HINTERNET,DWORD,DWORD,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPVOID);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:580:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpSetOption(HINTERNET,DWORD,LPVOID,DWORD);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:581:1: error: 'WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK' does not name a type; did you mean 'WINHTTP_OPTION_CALLBACK'?
 WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK WINAPI WinHttpSetStatusCallback(HINTERNET,WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK,DWORD,DWORD_PTR);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 WINHTTP_OPTION_CALLBACK
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:582:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpSetTimeouts(HINTERNET,int,int,int,int);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:583:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpTimeFromSystemTime(const SYSTEMTIME *,LPWSTR);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:584:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpTimeToSystemTime(LPCWSTR,SYSTEMTIME*);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:585:1: error: 'WINBOOL' does not name a type; did you mean 'V_BOOL'?
 WINBOOL     WINAPI WinHttpWriteData(HINTERNET,LPCVOID,DWORD,LPDWORD);
 ^~~~~~~
 V_BOOL
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:123:91: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
     INTERNET_SCHEME_PARTIAL = -2,INTERNET_SCHEME_UNKNOWN = -1,INTERNET_SCHEME_DEFAULT = 0,INTERNET_SCHEME_FTP,INTERNET_SCHEME_GOPHER,
                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:123:91: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
In file included from .\http.cpp:4:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:122:16: note: to match this '{'
   typedef enum {
                ^
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:123:91: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
     INTERNET_SCHEME_PARTIAL = -2,INTERNET_SCHEME_UNKNOWN = -1,INTERNET_SCHEME_DEFAULT = 0,INTERNET_SCHEME_FTP,INTERNET_SCHEME_GOPHER,
                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:4:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:127:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ',' token
   } INTERNET_SCHEME,*LPINTERNET_SCHEME;
                    ^
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:127:22: error: 'INTERNET_SCHEME* LPINTERNET_SCHEME' redeclared as different kind of symbol
   } INTERNET_SCHEME,*LPINTERNET_SCHEME;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:46:31: note: previous declaration 'typedef int* LPINTERNET_SCHEME'
 typedef int INTERNET_SCHEME, *LPINTERNET_SCHEME;
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:4:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:224:5: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct HTTP_VERSION_INFO HTTP_VERSION_INFO'
   } HTTP_VERSION_INFO,*LPHTTP_VERSION_INFO;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:543:3: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct HTTP_VERSION_INFO HTTP_VERSION_INFO'
 } HTTP_VERSION_INFO, *LPHTTP_VERSION_INFO;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:4:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:224:24: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct HTTP_VERSION_INFO* LPHTTP_VERSION_INFO'
   } HTTP_VERSION_INFO,*LPHTTP_VERSION_INFO;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:543:23: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct HTTP_VERSION_INFO* LPHTTP_VERSION_INFO'
 } HTTP_VERSION_INFO, *LPHTTP_VERSION_INFO;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:4:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:267:5: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct URL_COMPONENTSW URL_COMPONENTSW'
   } URL_COMPONENTSW,*LPURL_COMPONENTSW;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:481:24: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct URL_COMPONENTS URL_COMPONENTSW'
 typedef URL_COMPONENTS URL_COMPONENTSW;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:4:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:267:22: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct URL_COMPONENTSW* LPURL_COMPONENTSW'
   } URL_COMPONENTSW,*LPURL_COMPONENTSW;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:482:26: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct URL_COMPONENTS* LPURL_COMPONENTSW'
 typedef LPURL_COMPONENTS LPURL_COMPONENTSW;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winnt.h:9,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/minwindef.h:163,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:8,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:69,
                 from .\http.cpp:3:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:269:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct URL_COMPONENTSA URL_COMPONENTS'
   __MINGW_TYPEDEF_AW(URL_COMPONENTS)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:480:3: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct URL_COMPONENTS URL_COMPONENTS'
 } URL_COMPONENTS, *LPURL_COMPONENTS;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winnt.h:9,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/minwindef.h:163,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:8,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:69,
                 from .\http.cpp:3:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:270:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct URL_COMPONENTSA* LPURL_COMPONENTS'
   __MINGW_TYPEDEF_AW(LPURL_COMPONENTS)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:480:20: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct URL_COMPONENTS* LPURL_COMPONENTS'
 } URL_COMPONENTS, *LPURL_COMPONENTS;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\http.cpp:4:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wininet.h:1629:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
 }
 ^
```

Comment: strange that error only here, if take to account that you not include *windows.h*.  open your *winhttp.h* and look how *WinHttpOpen* here declared. may be inside some conditions

Answer (score 2):

`#pragma comment` is used for the Visual C++ Compiler and will be ignored by the gcc/g++. You can use command-line instead of `#pragma` when compiling with MinGW: `-lwinhttp`.

Additionally the `#include <windows.h>` required to be added.

Code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>

int main(void) {

    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    WinHttpOpen(L"A WinHTTP Example Program/1.0", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile command like this:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -lwinhttp
```

Comment: Yes, if i use only WinHttpOpen start working, but if you add variables `HINTERNET ` the compiler throw: `C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winhttp.h:32:9: error: 'LPVOID' does not name a type; did you mean 'VOID'?
 typedef LPVOID HINTERNET;` … i'm confuse :(

Comment: @reg3x_mr I can't reproduce this error. It works for me. Have you added the `#include <windows.h>`?

Comment: Han, i edit my post :) Yes, i have ```#include <windows.h>```

Comment: @reg3x_mr Even without variables `HINTERNET` your presented code still produce errors. Because including both `winhttp.h` and `wininet.h` cause many redefinition errors. Removing `#include <wininet.h>` solves the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

a little bit late, but my problem is solve! Main reason why, is the order of the libraries. I put <windows.h> in first line, and that did solve my error :)